# Is Hardhat calculating Event Signatures Wrongly?

Tags: hardhat, events

I have this event on my code
`event CrowdSourceCreated(address indexed contractAddress, address indexed creator, uint indexed amount);`. As per eth documentation, to get this event signature I will need to hash the event name and the params which is this `ethers.id("CrowdSourceCreated(address,address,uint)")`. Now when I do this, I get this hash 0x4ab3f8efdb1b05ed7aab7d0d63f0e4a8af9a673ebef82aaae36e6528bd94b3ac. But hardhat returns an empty array when I pass this as my topic. I called getLogs on the blockHash without passing a topic and hardhat returns an event response with a different hash as the event signature.

```
    provider: JsonRpcProvider {},
    transactionHash: '0xf30efb07d9250e96db3d46f03d1ebc731029bf86da34a4252f9ecdac6a95593d',
    blockHash: '0x5711386d47b932241a6672e33fba275192c8ae26d28411c468c1cc071249fa14',
    blockNumber: 9326342,
    removed: false,
    address: '0xd3924Aed3dbE4bdBC12FBc5917bBa7202141FE6F',
    data: '0x',
    topics: [
      '0x1bbdae750438509a344ebf8a0bf269e2dddc83b20244f7b8a9772131f260313c',
      '0x000000000000000000000000a436585577918a038df63116216331258b19017d',
      '0x000000000000000000000000f39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266',
      '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8'
    ],
    index: 1,
    transactionIndex: 0
  }
]
```

I would wager I'm doing something wrong with my hash calculation. But I can't seem to find what it is. I have used online tools to check my event signature and it's the same with ethers, so why does Hardhat generate a different one?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you don't use an alias when specifying the data type eg:
instead of
`ethers.id("CrowdSourceCreated(address,address,uint)")`, the correct format is  `ethers.id("CrowdSourceCreated(address,address,uint256)")`